# Flutter remove/add Items from/to ScrollablePostionedList without AnimatedList

Tags: flutter, list, listview, animation

I have a problem with animations and lists.
Since I use the ScrollablePositionedList package in my app, I can't use the AnimatedList widget.
So I wanted to create my own animations that appear when a new item is added or removed from a list.

I have my code so far, but unfortunately there is a bug where I can't get any further.
I have written a small demo.
Is this the right approach? I am trying to trigger an animation at the initstate and when the item is clicked, the "reverse" function is triggered by the AnimationController and after a certain time, the item is actually deleted.

However, when deleting, another element is also directly reduced in size, not just the currently deleted element.
However, the animation should only be executed for the clicked element and not for other elements.

Also: The "key: ObjectKey(snapshot.users[index])" in the listview helps to remove the bug, but after deleting the entire list is updated, which looks really stupid.
Can this problem be solved? Then i would still be able to use the UserItem with the animations.

I hope you can help me here.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:list_add_delete_with_animation/user_model.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/scrollable_positioned_list.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider<UserModel>(
        create: (_) => UserModel(),
        child: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<User> users = [];
  final ItemScrollController itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
  final ScrollOffsetController scrollOffsetController =
      ScrollOffsetController();
  final ItemPositionsListener itemPositionsListener =
      ItemPositionsListener.create();
  final ScrollOffsetListener scrollOffsetListener =
      ScrollOffsetListener.create();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Consumer<UserModel>(builder: (context, snapshot, child) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    snapshot.addUsers(
                      User(
                        "User_${snapshot.users.length}",
                        snapshot.users.length + 1,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
                    itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
                    scrollOffsetController: scrollOffsetController,
                    itemPositionsListener: itemPositionsListener,
                    scrollOffsetListener: scrollOffsetListener,
                    itemCount:
                        snapshot.users.isNotEmpty ? snapshot.users.length : 0,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      User user = snapshot.users[index];
                      return UserItem(
                        // key: ObjectKey(snapshot.users[index]),
                        user: snapshot.users[index],
                        onRemove: () {
                          snapshot.deleteUser(user);
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  User(this.name, this.age);
}

class UserItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;
  final VoidCallback onRemove;

  const UserItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.user,
    required this.onRemove,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserItemState createState() => _UserItemState();
}

class _UserItemState extends State<UserItem>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _sizeAnimation;
  final _size = 0.0;
  final _sizeEnd = 150.0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
    );
    _sizeAnimation =
        Tween<double>(begin: _size, end: _sizeEnd).animate(_controller)
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });

    _controller.forward();
  }

  void startRemoveAnimation() {
    _controller.reverse();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 350), () {
      if (mounted) {
        widget.onRemove();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        startRemoveAnimation();
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: _sizeAnimation.value,
        height: _sizeAnimation.value,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(25),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(widget.user.name),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```